# What can I make with the broken corn chips at the bottom of the bag?

Tags: culinary-uses, tortilla-chips

Once I've eaten all the biggish chips with salsa, there are a bunch of small-to-crumb sized corn chips left. I always think I'll eat them plain later, but I happen to want more salsa now...and they sit until they get stale. But they're so delicious (so full of fat and salt!), it seems to me I ought to be able to incorporate them into a dish. But what?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

They're generally good for adding some crunch, too, not just the flavor. A few things that come to mind:

- on top of a salad - my family does a roasted corn and black bean salad; also probably good instead of croutons in salads where they're a better flavor/style fit
- garnish on a soup - tortilla soup, sopa de elote...
- as part of a breading for fish or chicken (or anything else to bake or fry)

In general, anywhere you would use breadcrumbs, tortilla chip crumbles might find a place. If you're afraid they're too salty, you could always put dump them in a sieve and shake some of the really small bits out, leaving the more sizable bits of chip.

Comment: Not just on a soup, in a soup. Add the small chips to puréed soups and cook them in. The chip crumbs soften, and can be blended in to help thicken the soup.

Comment: @Bruce: True enough; I was just going for uses that left the chips more noticeable.

Comment: They're also good for breading (pan|deep) fried foods. Dredge, egg wash, dredge in chips, fry!

Comment: Thanks! Tried the soup garnish approach and it worked beautifully. And I hadn't thought about them as breadcrumb alternatives; now I see plenty of uses...

Comment: I'd also add sprinking it on top of casseroles, instead of breadcrumbs for a little extra crunch.

Comment: Very nice answer and useful answer!

Answer (score 2):

Throw them in the frying pan with an egg. You'll get a crispy crunchy egg tortilla matrix.

Answer (score 1):

I sometimes add the crumbs (or more, if there's not enough) to chili (chili con carne) as a thickener.

Answer (score 0):

I think Angelina Jolie (of Tomb Raider fame) uses these crumbs for crumb crust. Not sure about that factoid, but hey. You can actually use these crumbs that way.

Answer (score -1):

Put them on top of a tuna casserole with peas , celery , cream of mushroom  soup, garlic , onions , bell peppers ( if you like them ) some cumin , coriander , a little curry , tuna , spinach fettuccine ...I don't think  I'm leaving anything out ...yum , just made myself hungry , damn!

Answer (score -6):

Fun fact: You know how there is always an exact weight on your bag on corn chips, even though corn chips are irregularly sized? You ever wonder how they come to that exact weight, because, legally, if the weight were off they could be sued (for false advertising)?

The answer is salt. They add salt to make up the different in weight.

Now what would you like to do with the stuff at the bottom of the bag?

Comment: Ouch. Still, the chunks I have at the bottom are too yellow and too large to *just* be salt. :)

Comment: My local corn chip provider lists the ingredients as corn & oil, nothing else. There is no salty taste etc. So it depends where you buy them. I just put the left overs on the compost heap, you do have a one don't you?

Comment: @TFD The OP said _(so full of fat and salt!)_ so I think you don't share suppliers :D

Comment: Surely it's also possible to simply put chips into a bag until it's the right weight? This seems like it might be overly cynical. More likely it's just salty because crumbles tend to include proportionally more salt from the surfaces of the chips.

Comment: Some manufacturers do add the salt last, or add an extra dose of salt last, but it's not to make up the weight: it's because they know that salt is heavier than the chips, and so will migrate down to the bottom, leaving the top chips less salty than desired.

Comment: @jefromi: The reason I know this factoid is because an uncle of mine worked for IBM in the '80's and figured out a way to balance the bags via algorithm, and was told (curtly) by a major chip producer that this was unnecessary for the reason I stated above.

Comment: Yikes. Well, let's hope not all of them are like that. The tortilla chips I buy certainly aren't just a pile of salt at the bottom.

Comment: @jefromi: It's probably not the same for high-end producers. This was a mass market brand, and I, at least, remember what mass market chips were like 25 years ago.

Comment: Do you have anything at all to support this "fact"? I've actually seen the machines that bag chips like this, they use very accurate scales and they fill them equal to or greater than their marked weight. There is no special "salt adding" process in the examples I've seen. Also, the weight of the bag has nothing to do with the size of the chips, at least not in the way you allude to you in your fun fact.

Comment: I'm not going to vote this down any more since apparently that's already been covered, but this should really have been a comment since it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Depending on the type of chip and the grain size of the salt, you could add one chip or (very approximately) 1/2 teaspoon of salt. I'm pretty sure the difference in weight is made up by (effectively) adding one more chip.